# Python - Sort numbers out of list

Tags: python, sorting

This script outputs me a result of percentages per number of input words found in each file. For example if I enter two words and file1 has both, it will give 100%, if it only has 1, it will give 50% and if it does not have any it will give 0%. But I need it in the output to order the files descendingly according to the percentages, I already tried several things but could not achieve it:

This is my script:

buscador.py:

```
archivo = ''
#buscar = input("Ingrese lo que desea buscar: ")
buscar = 'de talle al suyo'
words = buscar.split(" ") #Separo la cadena de texto en palabras.
total = len(words) # Cuento la cantidad total de palabras en mi lista.
num_file = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

def contar_palabras (archivo):
  try:    
    with open(archivo, "r") as arch_obj:
        lineas = arch_obj.read()
  except FileNotFoundError:
    mensaje = "El archivo " + archivo + " no existe."
    print(mensaje)
  else:
    cant = 0
    for i in words: #Para cada palabra de la lista:
        if " " + i + " " in lineas or " " + i + "." in lineas or "" + i + " " in lineas or " " + i + "" in lineas or " " + i + "" in lineas : #Si la palabra existe en el archivo.
            cant = cant+1 #Suma 1 a la variable cant que indica la cantidad de palabras que existen en el file.
            perc = 100 * cant / total
        else: #Si no existe la palabra, no suma nada y solo calcula el porcentaje.
            perc = 100 * cant / total
        archivos.append((archivo, perc)) #agregamos como tupla
    archivos = sorted(perc, reverse=True)

num = 0
archivos = ['file{}'.format(num) +'.txt'] #Creo lista con nombre de los files
archivos.pop(0) #Elimino el elemento 0 del array

for i in num_file:
    num = num+1
    archivos.append('file{}'.format(num) +'.txt') #Agrego un file a inspeccionar

for i in archivos:
contar_palabras(i)
```

The output it throws at me is the following:

```
file1.txt: 100%
file2.txt: 75%
file3.txt: 75%
file4.txt: 75%
file5.txt: 75%
file6.txt: 75%
file7.txt: 100%
file8.txt: 75%
file9.txt: 75%
file10.txt: 75%
```

And in this example I need it to stay like this:

```
file1.txt: 100%
file7.txt: 100%
file2.txt: 75%
file3.txt: 75%
file4.txt: 75%
file5.txt: 75%
file6.txt: 75%
file8.txt: 75%
file9.txt: 75%
file10.txt: 75%
```

file1.txt:

> Doña Uzeada de Ribera Maldonado de Bracamonte y Anaya era baja, rechoncha, abigotada. Ya no existia razon para llamar talle al suyo. Sus colores vivos, sanos, podian mas que el albayalde y el soliman del afeite, con que se blanqueaba por simular melancolias. Gastaba dos parches oscuros, adheridos a las sienes y que fingian medicamentos. Tenia los ojitos ratoniles, maliciosos. Sabia dilatarlos duramente o desmayarlos con recato o levantarlos con disimulo. Caminaba contoneando las imposibles caderas y era dificil, al verla, no asociar su estampa achaparrada con la de ciertos palmipedos domesticos. Sortijas celestes y azules le ahorcaban las falanges
> hola
> dale
> dale
> bueno gracias chau
> bueno gracias
> si

file2 to 10 (they are all the same):

> dale dale
> dale
> dale
> capo
> nafta
> catarro
> perro
> adios
> hola
> de talle

When it runs it fails because "TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable" the "perc" variable is float, but if I cast it to 'int' it fails for the same reason

Comment: What did you try? How didn't it work?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Your posted code is not at all minimal: 30 lines and file reading, simply to ask about sorting a list.

Comment: @wwii when I do that and try to sort the list it fails: "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable"

Answer (score 0):

You can simply apply another sorting after you get your result. Naming the list `l`, you can do:

```
sorted(l, key=lambda s: float(s.split()[-1][:-1]), reverse=True)
```

The lambda function is trying to extract the percentage from the line and use that as the sorting key.

Output:

```
['file1.txt: 100%',
 'file7.txt: 100%',
 'file2.txt: 75%',
 'file3.txt: 75%',
 'file4.txt: 75%',
 'file5.txt: 75%',
 'file6.txt: 75%',
 'file8.txt: 75%',
 'file9.txt: 75%',
 'file10.txt: 75%']
```

Comment: it failes because of this: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple